# How to save a pandas dataframe when a column contains sets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet, pyarrow

When trying to save a pandas dataframe where a column contains set (see example below)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col_set": [{"A", "B", "C"}, {"D", "E", "F"}]})
df.to_parquet("df_w_col_set.parquet")
```

The following error is thrown:

```
ArrowInvalid: ("Could not convert {'C', 'B', 'A'} with type set: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type", 'Conversion failed for column col_set with type object')
```

How can one save this kind of dataframe and avoid the error above?

Some semi related posts mention providing a yarrow schema but I'm not clear on what type to use when consulting [pyarrow datatypes](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/datatypes.html).

Code was run with `python 3.7.4`, `pandas==1.3.0` and  `pyarrow==3.0.0`

Mainly looking for a solution where upgrades are not needed or really minimized(to avoid breaking other dependencies).

Comment: Can you update your versions or it's not possible. With Pandas 1.4.1, PyArrow 6.0.1 and Python 3.9.7 your code works but when you read your file with `pd.read_parquet` the `set` is converted to a `list`.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid upgrades as it will likely break other dependencies in the environment used. Clarified in the post too based on your useful feedback/question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As workaround, you can convert your `set` to string and use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate your string as `set`:

```
import ast

df.astype({'col_set': str}).to_parquet('data.parquet')
df1 = pd.read_parquet('data.parquet') \
        .assign(col_set=lambda x: x['col_set'].map(ast.literal_eval))
print(df1)

# Output
     col_set
0  {C, B, A}
1  {F, E, D}
```

Or you can convert your set to `tuple` (or `list`) then revert to `set`:

```
df.assign(col_set=df['col_set'].map(tuple)).to_parquet('test.parquet')
df1 = pd.read_parquet('test.parquet') \
        .assign(col_set=lambda x: x['col_set'].map(set))
print(df1)

# Output
     col_set
0  {C, B, A}
1  {F, E, D}
```

You can also use `pickle.dumps` and `pickle.loads` to serialize your `set`:

```
import pickle

df.assign(col_set=df['col_set'].map(pickle.dumps)).to_parquet('test.parquet')
df1 = pd.read_parquet('test.parquet') \
        .assign(col_set=lambda x: x['col_set'].map(pickle.loads))
print(df1)

# Output
     col_set
0  {C, B, A}
1  {F, E, D}
```

In fact, you can choose any (un)serialization method (except JSON because `set` does not exist).